# How to automatically set time in a date/time field?

Tags: craft3, datetime

For a specific kind of entry I need the time in a date/time field to either automatically display as 23:00/11pm on the user dashboard, or, permanently set the time on that date/time field to 23:00/11pm.

Comment: So, you want that field to have 11pm as default value if nothing was set?

Comment: @Johannes Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Maybe you can use this plugin: `doublesecretagency/craft-cpjs`. Then target your field and change its value on load using JavaScript. Not the cleanest, but probably the easiest.

Comment: Yes, you could do this by injecting JS and manipulate the `<input>` or by writing a custom module that modifies the value. Do you need further advice on that?